# is there any simple way for this case in R, using sapply or another way but not using loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, dplyr, sapply

i have 3 matrix, first :

```
> QualiVars
   Qlvar1 Qlvar2
1      A      Q
2      B      Q
3      A      R
4      C      Q
```

second matrix is :

```
> cat.centroid
[[1]]
    Values        V1       
 1     A    0.4164760 
 2     B    0.3112128 
 3     C    0.2723112 
[[2]]
    Values        V1        
 1      Q   0.7665904 
 2      R   0.2334096
```

the third matrix:

```
> distForAll
   VarIndex xVal yVal DistBetPair
1        1    A    B   0.5000000
2        1    A    C   0.5000000
3        1    B    C   0.6666667
4        2    Q    R   0.6666667
```

maybe its kinda complicated, i will start from "A" (first data from first Matrix). it will compare to second matrix cat.centroid[[1]] because A from first column and it will compare to the first list of second matrix[[1]]. the condition is take the Values first list from second matrix except "A", so we will get

```
Values        V1    
2     B    0.3112128 
3     C    0.2723112
```

then from the matrix above, it will corresponding to the third matrix. 
remember the first data from first matrix is "A". and from the above matrix i got "B" and "C" so i will take

```
 VarIndex xVal yVal DistBetPair
1        1    A    B   0.5000000
2        1    A    C   0.5000000
```

from the third matrix, so the final result will be

```
Values        V1      xVal yVal DistBetPair
2     B    0.3112128  A    B   0.5000000
3     C    0.2723112  A    C   0.5000000
```

then calculate 0.3112128*0.5 + 0.2723112*0.5 = 0.29. do this step for all data from first matrix.

```
0.29 ... ...
...  ... ...
...  ... ...
...  ... ...
```

im thinking about using sapply, but i have no idea.

Comment: If you edit this question to include generating the matrices it will make it much easier for others to respond and help you with an answer.